# Latin jūs and sūcus, and the words in Romance languages

Tags: etymology, latin, french, spanish

Why is French *jus* said to be from Latin *jūs* or *iūs*, while Spanish *jugo* is said to be from the Latin *sūcus*? I don't know if there's a link between *sūcus* and *jūs*, but *jus* and *jugo* look like they are from the same root.

I saw it in several dictionaries, but for example, here is what Wiktionary says [about *jus*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/jus#Etymology_3) and [about *jugo*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/jugo#Etymology_3).

Comment: It's not uncommon for things to look similar by coïncidence. These "false cognates" show up all over the place, and just happen.

Comment: I don't know what sound change explains Latin /s/ → Spanish /x/, but I think I don't see a way Latin *iūs* would become Spanish *ju**go***: the ending seems unjustified. I see that as a stronger argument against than for, even if the /s/→/x/ sound change proved obscure, although I bet someone else will shed light on it. Italian has *succo* and *sugo* with similar meanings, from the two variants of *sūcus*... if you know French, you may be led to wonder "why is this not the same root as French?", but knowing Italian, I'd similarly wonder "how would this not be the same word as Italian?".

Comment: Maybe @Draconis can dig up the sound change in record speed, as well as explain how this is a clearly a language-specific grammar or usage question, since both those things are, at this stage, not shown here.

Answer (score 8):

sorry - no time to write, just posting a screenshot from [Penny 2002](https://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/languages-linguistics/european-language-and-linguistics/history-spanish-language-2nd-edition):

[image]

Comment: It's very useful, I bookmark this, but why dictionary gives "succus" and "jus", and not the same root word for both in this case?

Comment: @Quidam because the concept of genetic root does not include the possibility of convergence. Why are all linguists adamant about the fairy tale of the unconditioned sound change, even if they do not come from the same parents: convergence!

Comment: @Quidam I'm afraid I don't understand your question.

Comment: @Quidam because in the Spanish case, the root word is *succus*, and in the French case, it's *jus*. The snippet provided explains how the Spanish is derived, and shows it is not a unique case.